# App is finished running when I push 'home button'

Tags: iphone, ios7

I am developing a app in the latest develop environment using Xcode5 with iOS7.1 SDK on Mavericks.

I have one problem after updating Xcode and iOS7.1 SDK.

The problem is that when I push home button, the app is finished immediately.

Before updating Xcode, my app was still running for 10 minutes even I pushed home button

(both in a simulator and a real device).

Also the applicationDidEnterBackground: is not working because of finishing.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, until I did this:

1. Find you info.plist file
2. Inside of the info.plist, find the "run in background" key
3. Set it's value to "No".

I hope it works for you. Good luck!